# Angular dependecy injection with multiple modules with same service name

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service, singleton

When you have 2 or more modules which are injected from another angular libraries which might be in-house or third party in an angular app, there might be chance that multiple modules might be having same class names used for services. In that case when a component is injecting the service , which instance of the service will be injected by angular?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, when you have multiple modules with the same class name, you need to be mindful of how you import and provide the classes to avoid conflicts and ensure correct dependency injection.

Let’s consider a scenario where you have two modules, ModuleA and ModuleB, both of which use a service named LoggerService.

ModuleA:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './module-a/data.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [LoggerService],
})
export class ModuleA {}
```

ModuleB:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './module-b/data.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [LoggerService],
})
export class ModuleB {}
```

In the above example, both ModuleA and ModuleB import and provide the LoggerService using the same class name.

When you want to use the LoggerService in a component that belongs to ModuleA or ModuleB, you need to import it correctly within the component.

ComponentA (belongs to ModuleA):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './module-a/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-a'
})
export class ComponentA {
  constructor(private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    // Use loggerService from ModuleA
  }
}
```

ComponentB (belongs to ModuleB):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './module-b/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-b'
})
export class ComponentB {
  constructor(private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    // Use loggerService from ModuleB
  }
}
```

By importing the LoggerService directly from the corresponding module, Angular’s dependency injection system will correctly resolve and provide the LoggerService from the respective module.

In summary, to avoid conflicts when multiple modules have the same class name, make sure you import the class from the appropriate module within your components. This way, Angular’s dependency injection will correctly identify and provide the instance of the class from the respective module.

Comment: Updated details can be found in the below blog link : https://medium.com/@kiranshashi14/angular-dependency-injection-resolution-of-services-with-multiple-modules-babe76753f64